# add value to object in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have 2 arrays

```
var labels = ["DESKTOP","MOBILE","TABLET"]

var chartData = ["100","10","15"]
```

And I need to combine these into one array with objects

```
    var myData = [{
    label: DESKTOP,
    value: 100},
{
    label: MOBILE,
    value: 10},
{
    label: TABLET,
    value: 15},
    ];
```

So far I've pushed labels into an array with new object

```
$.each(labels, function (index, item) {                            
      myData.push({
           label: item,
           value: ''
      });     
 });
```

I've done empty value, and now can't push value to an object in array. Just can't figure out how to push each value to new object in array. Help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Data is sample only.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var labels = ["DESKTOP", "MOBILE", "TABLET"];
var chartData = ["100", "10", "15"];
var myData = [];

labels.forEach(function(e, i) {
  myData.push({
    label: e,
    data: chartData[i]
  })
})

document.write(JSON.stringify(myData));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$.each(labels, function (index, item) {                            
  myData.push({
       label: item,
       value: chartData[index]
  });     
 });
```